# Setup UAC elevation takes too long

Tags: windows-installer, installation, uac, signature, elevation

The UAC elevation of my setup (MSI) takes too long (~20 seconds).

from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2008/03/31/why-does-it-take-so-long-to-see-the-uac-prompt-sometimes-diagnosing-slow-uac-prompts.aspx) I understand that this could be due to long signature test.

My setup itself is not signed so I guess something else that gets into my setup is checked for signature.

Is there anyway to check what in my setup causing this and how to improve this issue?

Also is there any other issue that can be the cause of that delay in elevation? like maybe the [Heuristic checks](http://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/uac-heuristics.html) for elevation? Is there anyway to workaround that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The article you mentioned offers a great explanation. So it should be your starting point.

The elevation request is handled by Windows Installer as part of your installation UI sequence. This sequence contains actions which are executed immediately one after another. The elevation is requested immediately, but it takes some time until Windows Installer processes it.

The only improvement you can try is using an EXE bootstrapper which **doesn't include** the MSI. Like the article suggests, a smaller file should take less to check.

Please note that just because you are not using a digital signature it doesn't mean that a check is not performed.

Comment: mmm but with the bootstrapper, doesn't it mean that the signature check and the elevation are just done later, for the new process which would be my setup?

Comment: No. If a bootstrapper launches your MSI, the installation process is a child process for that EXE. If a process is elevated, all child processes automatically use that elevation and do not request it anymore.

Comment: Well, this does not fully answer my question but it is the only answer I got and it is an acceptable workaround, so I accept this answer.